# WAS hosted WCF service activation

Tags: wcf, was, solace-mq, solace

Is there any way to have WCF service (hosted by WAS) activated by incoming message from the Solace queue?

I know that WAS is able to do this for MSMQ bindings.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, Solace Systems does not have support for Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) at this point in time.

As of SolOS 7.1.1, the supported interfaces are:

1. C
2. .NET
3. Java
4. JMS
5. JavaRTO (A low-latency Java Native Interface (JNI) wrapper for the C API.)
6. Javascript
7. Actionscript
8. Silverlight
9. REST
10. MQTT
11. OpenMAMA

Note that while there is no direct interface with WCF, it is still possible to make use of the REST interface that's built into the Solace appliance to initiate the WCF service.

In Solace, you would define a Rest Delivery Point.  When a message arrives on Solace for that endpoint, it opens an HTTP/REST connection to an IIS IP/Port and IIS in turn launches an application via WAS to consume the message.